# Firebase Storage rules not allow read or write

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I am having this bucket stracture, with a bucket named "Signatures" that stores all the signatures images:

[image: buckets]

Those are my rules:
[image: Storage rules]

Under the Signatures bucket I have a folder for the Organization name and another folder inside it for all of it's groups.

with those rules and folders everytime I try to read or write to those folders it's fails.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that if the parent folder is allowed to read or write, It doesn't means the same for the child folder.
It was solved by changing the rules from:

```
   match /Signatures/{organiztion}/{group} {
```

to:

```
   match /Signatures/{organiztion}/{group}/{file} {
```

Comment: If you want the permission to be recursive, you can use `{group=**}` at the end of the path. See the Firebase documentation on recursive wildcards here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/core-syntax#recursive_match_wildcards